# Pulling rows from .log file into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I have a very flat, simple log file (6 rows of which one row is blank) that I want to insert into a simple 5 column SQL Server table.

Please excuse my SQL ignorance as my knowledge around this topic is not educated.

Below is the `.log` file content :-

```
-----------Log File content start----------
07/30/2016 00:02:03 :  BATCH CLOSE SUMMARY

MerchantID - 000022673665
TerminalID - 013
BatchItemCount - 650
NetBatchTotal - 5095.00
----------Log file content end-------------
```

Below is the simple SQL Server table layout:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CCClose
(
    CloseTime NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    MercID NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    TermID NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    BatchCount NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    NetBatcTotal NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm hoping that somehow have each row looked at by SQL for example:

- if `.log` file like '*Batch close Summary*' then insert into CloseTime else
- if `.log` file like '*MerchantID*' then insert into MercID else
- if `.log` file like '*BatchItemCount*' then insert into BatchCount else
- if `.log` file like '*NetBatchTotal*' then insert into NetBatchTotal

Off course it would be great if the proper formatting for each column was in place but at this time I just looking at getting the .log file data populated from a directory of these logs.

I plan to use Crystal Reports to build on the SQL Server tables.

Comment: SQL would greatly prefer the data being read in as one row for each merchant id, batch count, etc.  Since your data is not in this format already, you might have to write a script to preprocess it before loading it into SQL.

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to be a simple process. You can probably do it with `bulk insert`.  The idea is to read it into a staging table, using:

- a record terminator of something like "----------Log file content end-------------" + newline
- a field separator of a newline
- a staging table with several columns of varchars

Then process the staging table to extract the values (and types) that you want. There are probably other options, if you set up a format file, but that adds another level of complexity.

I would read the table into a staging table with one line per row in the table. Then, I would:

- use window functions to assign a record number to rows, based on the "content start" lines
- aggregate based on the record number
- extract the values using aggregations, string functions, and conversions

Comment: Trying to use SSIS to deliver a package but having issues understanding this even more complex transformation. Seemed so straight forward what I am looking to do.